# Using matrix inversion of the diffusion equation to compute temperature distribution along a rod

Tags: python, matrix, nodes, differential-equations

my task is to compute the temperature distribution along a 1d rod as time moves forward.I used [this matrix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AxdI9.png), and the back-wards time equivalent formula is [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mqq21.png). My code is as follows- I've generated a grid of nodes and T seems to be being calulated at each position:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import linalg as lin
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#create 1d grid
N=50
xmax=50
x=np.linspace(0,xmax,N+1)
h=xmax/(N+1)
alpha=0.01
dt=1
print(x)
#create matrix

M=np.eye(N+1)
M=M*(1+(2*alpha*dt)/h**2)



for i in range(2,N+1):

     M[i-1,i]=-(alpha*dt)/h**2

for i in range(0,N-1):
     M[i+1,i]=-(alpha*dt)/h**2

M[0,0]=1
M[N-2,N-2]=1
print(M)


b=np.zeros((N+1,1))

    #set b.c.s
b[:,:]=20
b[N,:]=1000
print(b)

t=20




for j in range(0,t,1):

    LU, P = lin.lu_factor(M) 
    vector=lin.lu_solve((LU,P),b) 
    b=vector
    print(vector)


    plt.plot(x,vector, label='x')
#    plt.xlabel("k")
#    plt.ylabel("vector element")
#    pylab.legend(loc='upper right')
plt.show()
```

Now, the graph should look like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3NOT8.png)...but instead for different values of t (time) I get a graph that increases very sharply (almost exponentially) and one that doesn't represent the temperature distribution along a rod at all!(note: temp is on y axis and position on the x). I'm not sure if it's something wrong with my code or if I'm not setting the bounds/tolerance correctly. Can anyone see what the problem might be?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You're graph looks exponential because you set the end boundary condition to 1000, if you set the initial boundary to 1000 then it looks closer to the graph you suggested:

```
#set b.c.s
b[:,:]=20
b[0,:]=1000
```

Also I think you made a mistake here:

```
M[0,0]=1
M[N-2,N-2]=1
print(M)
```

I think it should be:

```
M[0,0]=1
M[N,N]=1
print(M)
```

since this sets the last value to 1 not the second to last diagonal element.

After changing M again to actually be the last element. I also think part of the issue is the amount of time we're giving it. The example graph you gave goes out to t = 1e9 seconds. So if we make t very large than only graph 10 of the solutions it looks a lot more similar to that example. Here is my code to do that:

```
t = 100000



soln = np.zeros((N+1, t))

for j in range(0, t, 1):

    LU, P = lin.lu_factor(M)
    vector = lin.lu_solve((LU, P), b)
    b = vector
    flat_list = []
    for sublist in vector:
        for item in sublist:
            flat_list.append(item)
    soln[:, j] = flat_list


for k in range(0, t, int(t/10)):
    plt.plot(x, soln[:, k], label='x')
#    plt.xlabel("k")
#    plt.ylabel("vector element")
#    pylab.legend(loc='upper right')


plt.show()
```

Comment: Hiya, thanks for the reply! h is actually the spacing of the grid nodes, and xmax is 50 because that's the length of the rod. So you get h by dividing length of rod by the 'precision' you want so to speak. So my grid nodes here have length 1. Alpha is actually the heat transfer co efficient in this scenario

Comment: See my edit in my response, there are just some timing issues.

Comment: thank you for your reply its very helpful! however the issue is that as t tends to infinity the graph tends to a straight with negative gradient- this isn't expected for a rod whose heat loss at the end of it is ignored. do you know why this might be- it's probably something to do with my B.C.s?

Comment: I think the B.C's should be fine. I am confused by the equations that you have. It doesn't look like the classic form of the heat equation.